# Removing a "row" from a structure array

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, runtime-error

This is similar to a question I asked before, but is slightly different:

So I have a very large structure array in matlab. Suppose, for argument's sake, to simplify the situation, suppose I have something like:

structure(1).name, structure(2).name, structure(3).name structure(1).returns, structure(2).returns, structure(3).returns (in my real program I have 647 structures)

Suppose further that structure(i).returns is a vector (very large vector, approximately 2,000,000 entries) and that a condition comes along where I want to delete the jth entry from structure(i).returns for all i.  How do you do this?  or rather, how do you do this reasonably fast?  I have tried some things, but they are all insanely slow (I will show them in a second) so I was wondering if the community knew of faster ways to do this.

I have parsed my data two different ways; the first way had everything saved as cell arrays, but because things hadn't been working well for me I parsed the data again and placed everything as vectors.

What I'm actually doing is trying to delete NaN data, as well as all data in the same corresponding row of my data file, and then doing the very same thing after applying the Hampel filter.  The relevant part of my code in this attempt is:

```
for i=numStock+1:-1:1
    for j=length(stock(i).return):-1:1
        if(isnan(stock(i).return(j)))
            for k=numStock+1:-1:1
                stock(k).return(j) = [];
            end
        end
    end
    stock(i).return = sort(stock(i).return);
    stock(i).returnLength = length(stock(i).return);
    stock(i).medianReturn = median(stock(i).return);
    stock(i).madReturn = mad(stock(i).return,1);
end;

for i=numStock:-1:1
    for j = length(stock(i+1).volume):-1:1
        if(isnan(stock(i+1).volume(j)))
            for k=numStock:-1:1
               stock(k+1).volume(j) = [];
            end
        end
    end
    stock(i+1).volume = sort(stock(i+1).volume);
    stock(i+1).volumeLength = length(stock(i+1).volume);
    stock(i+1).medianVolume = median(stock(i+1).volume);
    stock(i+1).madVolume = mad(stock(i+1).volume,1);
end;



for i=numStock+1:-1:1
    for j=stock(i).returnLength:-1:1
        if (abs(stock(i).return(j) - stock(i).medianReturn) > 3*stock(i).madReturn)
            for k=numStock+1:-1:1
                stock(k).return(j) = [];
            end
        end;
    end;
end;

for i=numStock:-1:1
    for j=stock(i+1).volumeLength:-1:1
        if (abs(stock(i+1).volume(j) - stock(i+1).medianVolume) > 3*stock(i+1).madVolume)
            for k=numStock:-1:1
                stock(k+1).volume(j) = [];
            end
        end;
    end;
end;
```

However, this returns an error:

"Matrix index is out of range for deletion.

Error in Failure (line 110)
                stock(k).return(j) = [];"

So instead I tried by parsing everything in as vectors.  Then I decided to try and delete the appropriate entries in the vectors prior to building the structure array.  This isn't returning an error, but it is very slow:

```
%% Delete bad data, Hampel Filter

% Delete bad entries
id=strcmp(returns,'');
returns(id)=[];
volume(id)=[];
date(id)=[];
ticker(id)=[];
name(id)=[];
permno(id)=[];
sp500(id) = [];

id=strcmp(returns,'C');
returns(id)=[];
volume(id)=[];
date(id)=[];
ticker(id)=[];
name(id)=[];
permno(id)=[];
sp500(id) = [];

% Convert returns from string to double
returns=cellfun(@str2double,returns);
sp500=cellfun(@str2double,sp500);

% Delete all data for which a return is not a number
nanid=isnan(returns);
returns(nanid)=[];
volume(nanid)=[];
date(nanid)=[];
ticker(nanid)=[];
name(nanid)=[];
permno(nanid)=[];

% Delete all data for which a volume is not a number
nanid=isnan(volume);
returns(nanid)=[];
volume(nanid)=[];
date(nanid)=[];
ticker(nanid)=[];
name(nanid)=[];
permno(nanid)=[];

% Apply the Hampel filter, and delete all data corresponding to
% observations deleted by the filter.

medianReturn = median(returns);
madReturn = mad(returns,1);

for i=length(returns):-1:1
    if (abs(returns(i) - medianReturn) > 3*madReturn)
        returns(i) = [];
        volume(i)=[];
        date(i)=[];
        ticker(i)=[];
        name(i)=[];
        permno(i)=[];
    end;
end

medianVolume = median(volume);
madVolume = mad(volume,1);

for i=length(volume):-1:1
    if (abs(volume(i) - medianVolume) > 3*madVolume)
        returns(i) = [];
        volume(i)=[];
        date(i)=[];
        ticker(i)=[];
        name(i)=[];
        permno(i)=[];
    end;
end
```

As I said, this is very slow, probably because I'm using a for loop on a very large data set; however, I'm not sure how else one would do this.  Sorry for the gigantic post, but does anyone have a suggestion as to how I might go about doing what I'm asking in a reasonable way?

EDIT: I should add that getting the vector method to work is probably preferable, since my aim is to put all of the return vectors into a matrix and get all of the volume vectors into a matrix and perform PCA on them, and I'm not sure how I would do that using cell arrays (or even if princomp would work on cell arrays).

EDIT2: I have altered the code to match your suggestion (although I did decide to give up speed and keep with the for-loops to keep with the structure array, since reparsing this data will be way worse time-wise).  The new code snipet is:

```
stock_return = zeros(numStock+1,length(stock(1).return));

for i=1:numStock+1
    for j=1:length(stock(i).return)
        stock_return(i,j) = stock(i).return(j);
    end
end

stock_return = stock_return(~any(isnan(stock_return)), : );
```

This returns an Index exceeds matrix dimensions error, and I'm not sure why.  Any suggestions?

Comment: To speed up your code you need to avoid using for-loops by making use of the vector operations in matlab.

Comment: I mean that's fine, I'd love to.  But how do I do an operation like what I'm showing above without using a for-loop?  I don't really know how to do something like this without one.

Comment: Ok, What is your true condition? Is it only isnan?

Comment: For the first part, yes.  But for the second part I have this abs(volume(i) - medianVolume) > 3*madVolume condition (and similar for returns) and I want to delete all data corresponding to points where this is true.  This is the one that I really wouldn't know how to do without the for-loop approach, and is probably the one that's slowing this thing to a crawl.

Comment: For edit2 my answer is at the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a convenient way to handle structures, therefore I would restructure the code so that instead of structures it uses just arrays.
For example instead of `stock(i).return(j)` I would do `stock_returns(i,j)`.

I show you on a part of your code how to get rid of for-loops.

Say we deal with this code:

```
for j=length(stock(i).return):-1:1
    if(isnan(stock(i).return(j)))
        for k=numStock+1:-1:1
            stock(k).return(j) = [];
        end
    end
end
```

Now, the deletion of columns with any `NaN` data goes like this:

```
stock_return = stock_return(:, ~any(isnan(stock_return)) );
```

As for the absolute difference from medianVolume, you can write a similar code:

```
% stock_return_length is a scalar
% stock_median_return is a column vector (eg. [1;2;3])
% stock_mad_return is also a column vector.

median_return = repmat(stock_median_return, stock_return_length, 1);
is_bad = abs(stock_return - median_return) > 3.* stock_mad_return;
stock_return = stock_return(:, ~any(is_bad));
```

Using a scalar for `stock_return_length` means of course that the return lengths are the same, but you implicitly assume it in your original code anyway.

The important point in my answer is using `any`. Logical indexing is not sufficient in itself, since in your original code you delete all the values if any of them is bad.

Reference to any: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/any.html.

---

If you want to preserve the original structure, so you stick to stock(i).return, you can speed-up your code using essentially the same scheme but you can only get rid of one less for-loop, meaning that your program will be substantially slower.

Comment: Ok I see, that will actually work well with the vectorized approach that I tried (my second attempt in the original message).  Will that work on the other vectors also?  Meaning if I use is_bad to determine which indices I want to remove, will that also work for volume?  So in short, to delete the corresponding entry from volume, would volume = volume(:,~any(is_bad)) work the same?  And if not, is there a way to identify which indices are removed from returns, and remove those same indices from volume?

Comment: Notice that the important trick here is `any`. You need to use that, not just logical indexing.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna give it a go and see what happens.  Wish me luck. :)

Comment: Well, it has sped up the code, but now your suggestion is giving me an error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Failure (line 114)
stock_return = stock_return(~any(isnan(stock_return)), : );"  (I changed it to delete rows instead of columns, but that shouldn't really matter).  Why would this return an index exceeds matrix dimensions error? EDIT: See EDIT2 in my original posting.

Comment: yes, it should matter! If you change it, then you say you throw away a complete return series for a stock i, if it has any NaN. Of course it also does not make sense for the matlab, since that expression is not changeable the other way around. If you want to change it you need to do at least `stock_return = stock_return(~any(isnan(stock_return')), : );`. Can you please vote up my answer if you held it useful?

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  You're absolutely right.  That was a product of me having not gone to bed and it being 8:30 or so in the morning.  Oh well, yes you're right, I want to delete a column (deletes the jth return from all series of stocks if any of them is NaN, which is indeed what I want).  Thanks.